# Create mullti section xml using boost property tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost, properties, tree

trying to create a multiple section xml inside property tree, like this:

```
<main>
    <SECTION id="1">
        <parameter>
           <name>Foo1</name>
           <name>Foo2</name>
        </parameter>
    </SECTION>
    <SECTION id="2">
        <parameter>
             <name>Bar1</name>
             <name>Bar2</name>
        </parameter>
    </SECTION>
</main>"
```

Testing with propertytree add and put but at the end the xml looks dirty:

```
<main>
    <SECTION id="1" id="2">
        <parameter>
           <name>Foo1</name>
           <name>Foo2</name>
           <name>Bar1</name>
           <name>Bar2</name>
         </parameter>
    </SECTION>
</main>
```

The code I used to get results:

```
static auto pretty = boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    ptree root;
    root.add("main.SECTION.<xmlattr>.id", 1);
    root.add("main.SECTION.parameter.name", "Foo1");
    root.add("main.SECTION.parameter.name", "Foo2");

    root.add("main.SECTION.<xmlattr>.id", 2);
    root.add("main.SECTION.parameter.name", "Bar1");
    root.add("main.SECTION.parameter.name", "Bar2");


    write_xml(std::cout, root, pretty);

    return 0; //a.exec();
}
```

Is it possible to get the result as is shown at the begining of topic?
How add a new node to this tree with new ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

static auto pretty = boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4);

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main()
{
    ptree root;
    ptree& section1=root.add_child("main.SECTION", ptree());
    section1.add("<xmlattr>.id",1);
    section1.add("parameter.name", "Foo1");
    section1.add("parameter.name", "Foo2");

    ptree& section2=root.add_child("main.SECTION", ptree());
    section2.add("<xmlattr>.id",2);
    section2.add("parameter.name", "Bar1");
    section2.add("parameter.name", "Bar2");


    write_xml(std::cout, root, pretty);

    return 0; 
}
```